# Android in-app billing getting purchases Issue

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm having an issue with my apps in-app billing. I thought it was working well for the last week, but I'm having an unexpected result.

I have about 10 items for sale. Each item sets a shared pref value to true when purchased/querying inventory if it is bought. One item, is a "Buy All" button, when bought, it's suppose to set the values for all the others to true. This was working well, the problem arises when I add new items to buy. The "buy all" should give access to those as well, but it seems it's not.

I'll try to make my code as simple as possible while still showing the needed info:
BaseActivity.java(where all in-app purchases set up):

```
//SKU FOR our products
static final String SKU_W31 = "workout_31";
static final String SKU_W32 = "workout_32";
static final String SKU_W37 = "workout_37";
static final String SKU_ALL = "all_workouts";

//is paid?
public boolean m31paid = false;
public boolean m32paid = false;
public boolean m37paid = false;
public boolean mAllPaid = false;

IabHelper mHelper;
IabBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    //SET FALSE FOR LIVE APP
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(false);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(LOG, "Problem setting up in app billing: " + result);
            } else Log.d(LOG, "set up correctly!");
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(BaseActivity.this);
            IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(LOG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");

            try {
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
            }
        }
    });
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(LOG, "Query inventory finished.");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;


Purchase w37Purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_W37);
        m37paid = (w37Purchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(w37Purchase));
        Log.d(LOG, "User has workout 37" + (m37paid ? "BOUGHT" : "NOT BOUGHT"));
        if (w37Purchase != null) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout37", true);
            editor.apply();
        }

Purchase w32Purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_W32);
        m32paid = (w32Purchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(w32Purchase));
        Log.d(LOG, "User has workout 32" + (m32paid ? "BOUGHT" : "NOT BOUGHT"));
        if (w32Purchase != null) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout32", true);
            editor.apply();
        }

Purchase w31Purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_W31);
        m31paid = (w31Purchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(w31Purchase));
        Log.d(LOG, "User has workout 31" + (m31paid ? "BOUGHT" : "NOT BOUGHT"));
        if (w31Purchase != null) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout31", true);
            editor.apply();
        }

Purchase wAllPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ALL);
        mAllPaid = (wAllPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(wAllPurchase));
        Log.d(LOG, "User has " + (mAllPaid ? "BOUGHT" : "NOT BOUGHT"));
        if (wAllPurchase != null) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout31", true);
            editor.putBoolean("workout32", true);
            editor.putBoolean("workout37", true);
            editor.apply();
        }

    }};
```

I then have the methods for buying that I put in the onClick of the corresponding buttons:

```
public void onBuy31ButtonClicked (View arg0) {
    Log.d(LOG, "Buy 31 button clicked.");
    if (m31paid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.already_bought, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.d(LOG, "launching purchase for 31");
    String payload = "";
    try {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_W31, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.purchase_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void onBuy32ButtonClicked (View arg0) {
    Log.d(LOG, "Buy 32 button clicked.");
    if (m32paid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.already_bought, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.d(LOG, "launching purchase for 32");
    String payload = "";
    try {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_W32, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.purchase_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void onBuy37ButtonClicked (View arg0) {
    Log.d(LOG, "Buy 37 button clicked.");
    if (m37paid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.already_bought, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.d(LOG, "launching purchase for 37");
    String payload = "";
    try {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_W37, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.purchase_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void onBuyAllButtonClicked (View arg0) {
    Log.d(LOG, "Buy all button clicked.");
    if (m32paid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.already_bought, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.d(LOG, "launching purchase for all");
    String payload = "";
    try {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_ALL, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.purchase_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My mPurchaseFinishedListener:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(LOG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Error purchasing: " + result);

            return;
        }
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_W30)) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout30", true);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        }
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_W31)) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout31", true);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        }
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_W32)) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout32", true);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        }
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_W37)) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout37", true);
            editor.apply();
            return;
       if(purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_ALL)) {
            editor.putBoolean("workout31", true);
            editor.putBoolean("workout32", true);
            editor.putBoolean("workout37", true);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        }
```

Then where the data is, I simply have an if statement to check the boolean value as such:

```
xpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("my_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean w31 = pref.getBoolean("workout31", false);
        boolean w32 = pref.getBoolean("workout32", false);
        boolean w37 = pref.getBoolean("workout37", false);

if (groupPosition == 2) {
                if(w31 == true) {
                    if (childPosition == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("workout", "w31w1");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if (childPosition == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("workout", "w31w2");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, but you need to purchase these workouts from the menu.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

All child items have the same code as above, switching out the w31 with w32 and w37.

I have taken out most purchases to try to cut back on code and still get the point across, but basically what is happening is 31 and 32 were added before, and then I used the purchase all button, they work. But I added 37 in a later update, and my theory was that the boolean value would change for it when it queries for all workouts and see it was purchased. In reality though, when I click 37 in the expandable list view, I get the toast saying it needs to be purchased, and when I go to the purchase page and click "Purchase All", I get the toast saying it was already purchased.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code? Thanks a lot, this is causing huge problems!

Answer (score 0):

Cause of async operations you may have a race condition. Your activity with expandable list view should be registered to all changes in your [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)).